# Kubernetes Load Balancer health status shows down and no nodes being added automatically

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have been trying to create an external load balancer to my DigitalOcean kubernetes cluster and everytime I create ine shows unhealthy or "Down" as the health status and also without nodes or droplets(in DOKS) being attached to the load balancer. I can attach manually from the DigitalOcean dashboard but it does automatically.

Can't also send an http request with the external ip of the load balancer via postman. get 503 Service Unavailable.

Here's the yaml configurations for ceating a load balancer:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: utloadbalancerservice
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-size-unit: "1"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-disable-lets-encrypt-dns-records: "false"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: utbuild
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```